# OpenGL: Square does not draw to window (No errors)

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I've followed these two tutorials: [Durian Software](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-1:-The-Graphics-Pipeline.html) and [LWJGL Tutorial Series](http://goharsha.com/lwjgl-tutorial-series/) to try to get a better understanding of OpenGL and LWJGL before trying to build a basic project, and I thought I understood the code. When I wrote the below code though, the square I'm trying to draw to the window did not show up. I'm really unsure as to why the below code doesn't draw the square.

Program Itself:

```
import java.util.*;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL12.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;

import java.lang.Math;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Engine extends Game{

    public int vertexShader, fragmentShader;
    ShaderProgram shaderProgram;
    public int programID;

    Space playArea;

    public Engine(int dimensionX, int dimensionY){
        super(dimensionX, dimensionY);
    }

    @Override 
    public void init(){

        playArea = new Space(100,100); // space is counted in block units
        playArea.entitiesInSpace.add(new Player("you", 0, 0));

        playArea.entitiesInSpace.get(0).vboID = makeBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, playArea.entitiesInSpace.get(0).vertices);
        playArea.entitiesInSpace.get(0).eboID = makeBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, playArea.entitiesInSpace.get(0).elementOrder);

        shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram();
        shaderProgram.attachVertexShader("./res/game.vs");
        shaderProgram.attachFragmentShader("./res/game.fs");
        shaderProgram.link();

        playArea.entitiesInSpace.get(0).uniformsPosition = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.programID, "position");

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta){
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        shaderProgram.bind();

        glUniform2f(playArea.entitiesInSpace.get(0).uniformsPosition, playArea.entitiesInSpace.get(0).posX, playArea.entitiesInSpace.get(0).posY);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, playArea.entitiesInSpace.get(0).vboID);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,
            2,
            GL_FLOAT,
            false,
            0,
            0
        );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, playArea.entitiesInSpace.get(0).eboID);
        glDrawElements(
            GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,
            4,
            GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
            0
        );

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float delta){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Engine(400,300).start();
    }

}
```

Vector Shader

```
#version 110

uniform vec2 position;

void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 110

//varying vec4 fragColor;

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The functions such as makeBuffer above definitely work since they were the same ones I used in the tutorials, as is the Game class and the ShaderProgram class. Additionally, the Player (which extends Entity) properly initializes the vertices and elementOrder arrays.

Comment: You will need a vertex attribute in your vertex shader. You're using a uniform instead. It looks like that one is supposed to be an offset, but you will still need an attribute that receives the coordinates of each vertex.

Comment: The above worked, if it was an answer I would mark it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From Reto Koradi:
You will need a vertex attribute in your vertex shader. You're using a uniform instead. It looks like that one is supposed to be an offset, but you will still need an attribute that receives the coordinates of each vertex.

Answer (score 0):

In your vertex shader use

```
in vec2 position;
```

Cheers,
Massimo

Comment: "in" does not work if #version is 110. It should be "attribute".